# r-markdown output stretch

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using rmarkdown to print a model -

````
```{R ForestModel, echo = FALSE, out.width = "100%"}
print(forest_model(res.cox))
```
````

and getting 
[image]

Where what I want to get is:
[image]

Comment: removing print() did no good

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It should be [minimal, but complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question should be clear and specific. (What's the difference between the two exactly? Provide your model, so we don't have to come up with our own data.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by treating as figure with

````
```{R Fig1_ForestModel, echo = FALSE, fig.width = 10, fig.asp = .50}
print(forest_model(res.cox))
```
````